# How to clean a .srt file without removing numbers that appear in the closed captions through VIM?

Tags: regex, vim, srt

It is known that `.srt` files are structured in blocks having 3 underlying parts, like this example:

```
228
00:39:06,680 --> 00:39:13,460
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
```

Now, let us suppose that in the closed captions there are some excerpts representing the speech of a speaker quoting a literary opus of someone else, like this additional example:

```
228
00:39:06,680 --> 00:39:13,460
According to Erasmus, book 1, chapter 23...
```

**Problem:** I wish to extract only the text from the `.srt` by deleting the frame number, the frame duration without erasing, however, the cardinal numbers that appear in the closed captions as quotations through **VIM**.

**Attempts:** By using regular expression and the `substitute` command, I have found a way to "delete" the duration line with `:%s/\d\d:\d\d:\d\d,\d\d\d --> \d\d:\d\d:\d\d,\d\d\d/ /g` and the numbers with the same idea, except now searching for each cardinal number entry with the option `/gc` to bypass those amidst the text.

However, I have a considerable amount of such quotations to extract, for which the cardinal number should be maintained. Selecting `yes/no` for all entries turns into a tedious task.

Since I have a lacking skill in using `regex`, I presume to say that there is, at least, a less "ugly" manner to perform the strategy aforementioned. Perhaps, a more elegant way to not only delete the unwanted portions, but also to recover a raw text without the frame and duration lines, like:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit met
According to Erasmus, book 1, chapter 23...
```

Someone knows how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Don't replace the content of the line with nothing, actually delete the line. Instead of using `:s/PATTERN//g`, use `:g/PATTERN/d` (see `:help :g`)
2. Anchor your patterns using `^` and `$` to only match lines that consist *entirely* of the thing you want to remove.

Put together:

```
:g/^\d\+$/d
:g/^\d\d:\d\d:\d\d,\d\d\d --> \d\d:\d\d:\d\d,\d\d\d$/d
```

(wow, that's a lot of "d").

This still has the possibility of nuking a "line of dialog" that consists *only* of digits, but it won't eat numbers that are just in the *middle* of a line.

To do a better job I would suggest using something a little more fit-for-purpose than Vim — either a programming language, or a subtitle editor :)

Comment: `:g/\d --> \d/d` will probably be enough for the second step.

Comment: @hobbs, thanks for replying! In fact, `g:` makes a better job and your points are noteworthy. I'll keep them in mind for the next times. Concerning programming and a fit-for-purpose tool, something might be useful indeed, but this was a "hobby" task, I would say. Then, `VIM` and `regexp` were the tools that jumped out to my sight to solve this quickly. Anyway, it's done. :) BTW, @romainl, your shorter suggestion also works fine. Thank you, as well!

Answer (score 1):

Things get a lot easier (although not necessarily better looking) if you use anchors:

```
:%s/\v(%^|\n)\zs\d+\n\d{2}(:\d{2}){2},\d{3} --\> \d{2}(:\d{2}){2},\d{3}$\n//
```

This considers the sequence numbers and the duration coupled, you don't need to worry about either matching in the middle of the text.

Comment: Hi, @SatoKatsura! This definitely "kills two birds with one stone" ;). I appreciate your collaboration. Getting to this surely would cost me too many hours of research and training about `regexp`. Thank you.